# PCI-DSS Helping customers with a third-party booking service

Tags: pci-dss

My clients are able to pay for services through a website EXAMPLE.COM.

Sometimes, a client will call on the phone looking to pay for services over the phone. I would like to use a device to visit EXAMPLE.COM and type in their information for them.

How can I do this, if at all, while remaining PCI-DSS compliant?

Comment: Example.com is your website?  Website allows guests to purchase items?

Comment: Are you an intermediate between these customers and example.com? or do you want to add the capacity to process CC payments over the phone?

Comment: EXAMPLE.COM is not my website, but rather a third-party that processes payments on my behalf. It could be my website though, if that changes the answer. I want to process CC payments over the phone using EXAMPLE.COM instead of a physical terminal.